# ドラッグ中に触っているViewのtagを取得する方法

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iphone

Objective-CでiOSアプリを作っていて、画像を複数枚並べてそれぞれにタグをつけています。

touchesMovedでドラッグ中に触っているViewのタグを取得したいのですが、
指を別のViewに移動した時も一番最初に触ったViewのタグの値だけがログに出力されます。

横1列に並べた4枚の画像にタグ（1~4）をつけ、左から順にドラッグした時

```
tag:1
tag:2
tag:3
tag:4
```

とその時触っているViewのタグが取れるイメージです。

1枚ずつタップした時はtouchesBeganが実行されて理想通りの値が取れるのですが、touchesMovedではできません。
どのようにしたらできるのでしょうか？

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    NSLog(@"tag:%ld",touch.view.tag);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITouch`のプロパティ`view`では、取得できないのは、経験なさったとおりですから、別の方法を考えましょう。
`UITouch`のメソッド`locationInView:`なら、メソッドを送った時点のタッチの座標を取得できます。これと、`UIView`のメソッド`hitTest:withEvent:`を組み合わせると、現在のタッチしている座標を含むViewのうち、最前面にあるViewが取得できます。

*ViewController.m*

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint thePoint = [touch locationInView: self.view];
    UIView *hitView = [self.view hitTest: thePoint withEvent: event];
    if (hitView != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Hit Test : tag = %ld", hitView.tag);
    }
}
```